# Where's the json file name/path of the 'width' value of the logo on Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I would like to make the logo bigger without losing quality of the image.
I increase the 'width' value of the logo image on the CSS.
Actual result: Blurry logo on desktop.
I think it is because of the reduced image that comes from the cdn - because if I change the image source to the original ( not reduced ) image it is not blurry.
I think the recuded image from the cdn is because I need to change the value on the JSON file.

I cannot find the JSON file and path that have the logo's 'width' key and value so I could change it.

[The website link](https://webfusion-homedepot-test.myshopify.com/)
Password to enter: saharsahar